# Trying to set up SP Framework - Can't get past Command Prompts

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, communication-site, script-editor-webpart

I'm trying to take the plunge into getting SP Framework set up so that I can add the modern script editor (frustrating that it isn't an easy process to set up).  I've followed numerous tutorials, but always get held up when trying to do the installations in the command prompt.  Each time I try "npm install", I get a list of errors that I don't understand.  I've downloaded the 16.15.0 LTS for NodeJS, and I've downloaded the modern script editor web part zip file:

[image]

But when I do the NPM Install on command prompt, this is what I get:

[image]

I don't know how to proceed with fixing this so that I can add some custom script to my Communication Site page.  I'm probably missing something simple, just not sure what.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your command prompt is not in the location where the SPFx project is.  As you can see by the error reported, `npm` is looking for a file called `package.json` in the same folder where the `npm install` command is being run.

According to your screenshot, it looks like your command prompt is open in

```
C:\Users\chsh7966
```

That zip file looks like it's in your Documents folder, so that would be

```
C:\Users\chsh7966\Documents
```

(assuming that `chsh7966` is your user account).

In addition, you will need to unzip that zip file. Look inside until you find the `package.json` file, then open a command prompt in that folder.

Considering that in Windows, expanding zip files tends to duplicate the folder, that may end up being

```
C:\Users\chsh7966\Documents\sp-dev-fx-webparts-main\sp-dev-fx-webparts-main
```

Regardless of what the actual path ends up being, though, the important part is that your command prompt needs to be open to the path of where the `package.json` file is.  Once you're there, *then* run `npm install`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  I was able to deploy the web part after fixing the path.